# Setting a variable like this $config['business']

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I was looking at some source code, specifically for Paypal IPN, and I noticed the author sets two variables in this format: $config['business'] and $config['different_text']

Is there a special reason other than the obvious organization for declaring my variables this way or is this Paypal settings?

Comment: Please paste the code where it comes from. I'm not sure what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is used to access elements of an array -- see [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in the PHP manual.

Here, you are working with an associative array, called `$config`, that's contain at least two entries : `business` and `different_text`.

Considering the name of the `$config` variable, you have at least two advantages :

- related variables are grouped together in one variable -- easier to have them together
- only one variable (`$config`) to work with

And, of course :

- You can add any number of configuration options without having to create a new variable : just add a new element to the `$config` array.

That being said, of course, maybe the paypal API you are using is actually expecting some data passed as an associative array containing those elements -- if it is the case, you don't have much of a choice.